# Text output from XML with XSLT with grouping

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem I cannot solve.

For each layer grouped by STRAT_ZONE the minimal values from DEPTHFROM_ZONE and maximum value DEPTHTO_ZONE are needed.

Grouping by STRAT_ZONE seems not an option, because the attribute can repeat itself.
A checkup line by line was an idea.

Does anyone have any tips, how to try reach the desired goal?

Datablock:

```
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Flysand unchained" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="0.00" DEPTHTO_ZONE="0.30" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Flysand unchained" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="0.30" DEPTHTO_ZONE="1.10" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Flysand unchained" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="1.10" DEPTHTO_ZONE="1.40" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Flysand unchained" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="1.40" DEPTHTO_ZONE="1.70" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="1.70" DEPTHTO_ZONE="1.80" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="1.80" DEPTHTO_ZONE="2.20" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="2.20" DEPTHTO_ZONE="2.60" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Flysand unchained" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="2.60" DEPTHTO_ZONE="2.80" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Flysand unchained" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="2.80" DEPTHTO_ZONE="2.90" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="2.90" DEPTHTO_ZONE="3.10" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="3.10" DEPTHTO_ZONE="3.40" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="3.40" DEPTHTO_ZONE="3.70" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="3.70" DEPTHTO_ZONE="4.50" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="4.50" DEPTHTO_ZONE="4.90" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Vulcanic" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="4.90" DEPTHTO_ZONE="6.00" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Vulcanic" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="6.00" DEPTHTO_ZONE="6.20" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Vulcanic" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="6.20" DEPTHTO_ZONE="6.30" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
```

Desired output:

```
ZONE "Flysand unchained" 0.00 1.70 -1
ZONE "Drifting sand" 1.70 2.60 -1
ZONE "Flysand unchained" 2.60 2.90 -1
ZONE "Drifting sand" 2.90 4.90 -1
ZONE "Vulcanic" 4.90 6.30 -1
```

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
the short XML part I try to convert:

```
<ZONES>
    
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Flysand unchained" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="0.00" DEPTHTO_ZONE="0.30" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Flysand unchained" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="0.30" DEPTHTO_ZONE="1.10" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Flysand unchained" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="1.10" DEPTHTO_ZONE="1.40" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Flysand unchained" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="1.40" DEPTHTO_ZONE="1.70" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="1.70" DEPTHTO_ZONE="1.80" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="1.80" DEPTHTO_ZONE="2.20" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="2.20" DEPTHTO_ZONE="2.60" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Flysand unchained" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="2.60" DEPTHTO_ZONE="2.80" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Flysand unchained" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="2.80" DEPTHTO_ZONE="2.90" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="2.90" DEPTHTO_ZONE="3.10" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="3.10" DEPTHTO_ZONE="3.40" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="3.40" DEPTHTO_ZONE="3.70" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="3.70" DEPTHTO_ZONE="4.50" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Drifting sand" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="4.50" DEPTHTO_ZONE="4.90" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Vulcanic" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="4.90" DEPTHTO_ZONE="6.00" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Vulcanic" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="6.00" DEPTHTO_ZONE="6.20" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>
<ZONE STRAT_ZONE="Vulcanic" DEPTHFROM_ZONE="6.20" DEPTHTO_ZONE="6.30" INDEX_ZONE="-1"/>

</ZONES>
```

The first try to get it as text, but without grouping:

```
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="ZONES|ZONE">
    
    <xsl:for-each select="ZONE">
        <xsl:if test="@STRAT_ZONE !=''">
            <xsl:text>ZONE </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',translate(@STRAT_ZONE, '&quot;',''),'&quot;',' ',@DEPTHFROM_ZONE,' ', @DEPTHTO_ZONE,' ',@INDEX_ZONE)" />
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    

</xsl:template>
```

And the result so far:

ZONE "Flysand unchained" 0.00 0.30 -1
ZONE "Flysand unchained" 0.30 1.10 -1
ZONE "Flysand unchained" 1.10 1.40 -1
ZONE "Flysand unchained" 1.40 1.70 -1
ZONE "Drifting sand" 1.70 1.80 -1
ZONE "Drifting sand" 1.80 2.20 -1
ZONE "Drifting sand" 2.20 2.60 -1
ZONE "Flysand unchained" 2.60 2.80 -1
ZONE "Flysand unchained" 2.80 2.90 -1
ZONE "Drifting sand" 2.90 3.10 -1
ZONE "Drifting sand" 3.10 3.40 -1
ZONE "Drifting sand" 3.40 3.70 -1
ZONE "Drifting sand" 3.70 4.50 -1
ZONE "Drifting sand" 4.50 4.90 -1
ZONE "Vulcanic" 4.90 6.00 -1
ZONE "Vulcanic" 6.00 6.20 -1
ZONE "Vulcanic" 6.20 6.30 -1

But would like to have it liek that:

```
ZONE "Flysand unchained" 0.00 1.70 -1
ZONE "Drifting sand" 1.70 2.60 -1
ZONE "Flysand unchained" 2.60 2.90 -1
ZONE "Drifting sand" 2.90 4.90 -1
ZONE "Vulcanic" 4.90 6.30 -1
```

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2 or 3? Then it might be that your are looking for `<xsl:for-each-group select="ZONE" group-adjacent="@STRAT_ZONE">`.

Comment: Some samples to introduce XSLT 2 or 3 grouping are at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info.

Comment: Hey, yes version 2.0.
group-adjacent looks promising by documentation. My first attemtp to get anything was something like that, but it somehow not works. Im still a newcomer, any help would be appreciated. The next step would be to evaluate the MIN and MAX values.

<xsl:for-each-group select="ZONE" group-by="@STRAT_ZONE">    
            
        <xsl:text>ZONE </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',@STRAT_ZONE,'&quot;',' ',@DEPTHFROM_ZONE,' ', @DEPTHTO_ZONE,' ',@INDEX_ZONE)" />
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text> 
            
 </xsl:for-each-group>

Comment: As the poster of a question, please just edit your question and add any code you tried there, minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem. `max(current-group()/@DEPTHTO_ZONE)` should help with the maximum but we can't tell where your grouping fails if you don't show us minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT, output you get.

Comment: Sorry, just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want

```
  <xsl:template match="ZONES">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="ZONE" group-adjacent="@STRAT_ZONE">
          <xsl:value-of 
            select="'ZONE', current-grouping-key(), min(current-group()/@DEPTHFROM_ZONE), max(current-group()/@DEPTHTO_ZONE), @INDEX_ZONE"/>
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```